# Monitor Data Loader Exports

Tags: data-loader, data-export, monitoring

We have few users with Data loader access. I would like to track their activity especially how do I monitor their exports please ?

Answer (score 1):

If they are using the bulk API to do the extracts you can monitor via Bulk jobs monitoring page in the set up.

For more info check the help [document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.monitoring_async_api_jobs.htm&type=5).

If they use SOAP then I recommend using solution like real time event monitoring [event monitoring](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.real_time_event_monitoring_overview.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5).

The event monitoring is a paid feature something to consider!